# Scheduled Task Logging for local system account

Tags: logging, scheduled-task

A few weeks ago I implemented a scheduled task that executes every 20 minutes on every workstation and server in the organization. This task runs under the local system account.

Since that date I have had a massive increase in the number of logon events (4624 and 4634) generated by all of my systems. This is a problem for my Splunk licensing.

Other than rewriting the executable this task fires into a full fledged service is there any way to change this behavior? I'd think that an executable run on the local box with local permissions wouldn't require authenticating to the domain controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that there is a ready way to eliminate this logging so I created a small service around the code for the original executable.

Comment: Just out of morbid curiosity, what did you have running every 20 minutes on every machine?

Comment: I needed a better way to address client side targeting. I have previous questions about it, including http://serverfault.com/q/347129/90351